# Python scipy not installed

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, installation, scipy

I am trying to install python scipy because I need it to work with some .mat files coming from matlab.
To install it, I downloaded Anaconda for Windows 64-bit, for Python 2.7 (my version) and run the file.exe.

However, when I type `import scipy.io` in the python command line, I receive the error:

`ImportError: No module named scipy.io`

I also tried to execute install scipy using the command prompt `conda install scipy`, which apparently installs it

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
mkl-11.3.3                 |                1       110.0 MB
conda-env-2.5.0            |           py27_0          69 KB
mkl-service-1.1.2          |           py27_1           7 KB
numpy-1.10.4               |           py27_2         2.9 MB
ruamel_yaml-0.11.7         |           py27_0         201 KB
conda-4.1.2                |           py27_0         245 KB
numexpr-2.5.2              |      np110py27_1         138 KB
scipy-0.17.1               |      np110py27_0        11.4 MB
scikit-learn-0.17.1        |      np110py27_1         3.5 MB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:       128.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

ruamel_yaml:  0.11.7-py27_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

conda:        4.0.5-py27_0       --> 4.1.2-py27_0
conda-env:    2.4.5-py27_0       --> 2.5.0-py27_0
mkl:          11.3.1-0           --> 11.3.3-1
mkl-service:  1.1.2-py27_0       --> 1.1.2-py27_1
numexpr:      2.5-np110py27_0    --> 2.5.2-np110py27_1
 numpy:        1.10.4-py27_0      --> 1.10.4-py27_2
 scikit-learn: 0.17.1-np110py27_0 --> 0.17.1-np110py27_1 
 scipy:        0.17.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.17.1-np110py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

To which I entered `y` of course.

Therefore, why does it now work? I do not think I have to modify any path in my windows advanced settings, since Anaconda should have done everything automatically, is that right? So what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the right python executable? What does `python --version` give you?

Comment: @syntonym Python 2.7.8

Comment: Sorry, I thought python would output path information. What does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` give you?

Comment: It provides me with this: `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe`. 
ArGIS is a geographic information system software that uses python for some functions. It is the main reason why I started to use python

Comment: This is not the conda python. You either need to execute the anaconda python (possibly by altering PATH in such a way that it comes first or by executing it manually by taking the complete path) or you could try to give theArcGIS access to the installed libraries in anaconda (via PYTHONPATH).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ sudo apt-get install python-scipy